# Oracle- Create list of weeks for each employee

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to query a list of dates (Monday of each week) for each individual employee and then join other tables on it. I can create the list of dates using

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE - ROWNUM,'WW') dt
FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < sysdate-to_date('1-JAN-17')
```

But how can I have this list for each employee in table:

```
SELECT Employee from table1
```

This would result in the table having the `number of records = number of weeks * number of employee`.

Comment: Sounds like you want a cross join. E.g. `select * from table1 cross join table2`, which would return all rows in table2 returned for each row in table1.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements that show which columns the table has. Also what are the date limits (start and end)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example based on Scott's EMP table, while DATES represent this (2018) year's Mondays; over here, ordinal number of Monday = 1; you might need to change that if it is different where you are. Result set is restricted to employees whose name begins with letter 'M' (so that the list wouldn't be too long).

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> with dates as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') + 1
  5    )
  6  select e.ename, d.datum
  7  from dates d cross join emp e
  8  where to_char(d.datum, 'd') = '1'    --> Monday in Croatia
  9    and substr(e.ename, 1, 1) = 'M'
 10  order by e.ename, d.datum;

ENAME      DATUM
---------- ----------
MARTIN     01.01.2018
MARTIN     08.01.2018
MARTIN     15.01.2018
MARTIN     22.01.2018
MARTIN     29.01.2018
MARTIN     05.02.2018
MARTIN     12.02.2018
MARTIN     19.02.2018
MARTIN     26.02.2018
MARTIN     05.03.2018
MARTIN     12.03.2018
MARTIN     19.03.2018
MARTIN     26.03.2018
MARTIN     02.04.2018
MARTIN     09.04.2018
MARTIN     16.04.2018
MARTIN     23.04.2018
MILLER     01.01.2018
MILLER     08.01.2018
MILLER     15.01.2018
MILLER     22.01.2018
MILLER     29.01.2018
MILLER     05.02.2018
MILLER     12.02.2018
MILLER     19.02.2018
MILLER     26.02.2018
MILLER     05.03.2018
MILLER     12.03.2018
MILLER     19.03.2018
MILLER     26.03.2018
MILLER     02.04.2018
MILLER     09.04.2018
MILLER     16.04.2018
MILLER     23.04.2018

34 rows selected.

SQL>
```